# Error while importing a library in github into Android

Tags: android

I was trying to use ion so I needed to use this library

I downloaded the zip file, extracted it put it into the root of my project inside a file called subProject.(only the ion folder not the other two) Then in my settings.gradle I added

```
 include ':app',':subProject:ion'
```

And I gave an error which said that there is no valid path in there so the project cant be cleaned. Then I changed it and added a compile statement to build.gradle

```
include ':app',':subProject'

compile project(':subProject:ion')
```

But when I try to use Ion.something it tells me it gives me an error since it cannot resolve what Ion is. How can I import this? The way I did it was the solution on the internet but it failed

Here is the code I try to use when I get an error for unknown symbol etc

```
Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load("http://www.example.com/abc/def/")
                .setBodyParameter("identifier", "foo")
                .setBodyParameter("email", "foo@foo.com")
                .setBodyParameter("password", "p@ssw0rd")
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                        // Result
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Why did you download it and extract it. Read the README, use Gradle. https://github.com/koush/ion#gradle

Comment: just use `dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}`

Comment: While using this should I download the project to main root?

Comment: I tried inserting that both build.gradle s in my root project and the one that is inside the app.  For the first case I got an error stating that could not find method compile() for arguments [com..........]. For the second case I could sync the project successfully but my code still does not know what an Ion is. Can you give me a complete guide into accomplishing this. Should I download the file? Where should I put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier, go to your build.grandle(Module:app) and add this code inside dependencies brackets like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 // leave code here as it is
}

dependencies{
 // other code here
 compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

If you want my opinion you can use picasso library from github simply adding compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'. I give you the link to check: [HAPPY CODING](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: I added that dependencies and cleaned rebuilt the project but I still get the same errors. Should I also download the rar file extract it and put it into somewhere in my project folder?

Comment: Ok I got the problem. I am used to do this in eclipse so I thought there was an auto import